# How to delete a record from a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following object:

```
var arrayOfStuff= {};
arrayOfStuff.chapter = [];

for (var k = 0; k < array2.length; k++) {
    arrayOfStuff.chapter.push({"title": array2[k][1], "page": array2[k][2]}) 
}
```

How can I get the ability to delete a record from the arrayOfStuff, without leaving a blank record behind?  I've tried load of stuff, and not posting them here because I know they are wrong!

i.e. i have

```
NameA, 2
NameB, 7
NameC, 11
NameD, 15
NameE, 20
```

and I call something like arrayOfStuff.chapter[2].remove(); to get:

```
NameA, 2
NameB, 7
NameD, 15
NameE, 20
```

PS: On a side question, what's the correct name for this type of object? I would associate it as a multidimensional array of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`splice()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp):

```
arrayOfStuff.chapter.splice(2,1);
// 2 : start index
// 1 : how many
```

Comment: best answer considering you included the '.chapter' part.

Answer (score 2):

To **remove an element from an array**, you can use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). The first parameter is the index of the first item you want to remove, the second parameter is the number of items you want to remove. The following example removes element 2.

```
arrayOfStuff.chapter.splice(2, 1);
```

This function works for arrays. If you want to **remove a property from an object**, you can use the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) keyword. If you use delete on an array, it leaves behind an empty element, though. The following example removes the property *chapter* from your *arrayOfStuff* object.

```
delete arrayOfStuff.chapter;
```

To answer your side question: *arrayOfStuff* is simply an object. It has a property called *chapter*, which is an array. There is no special name for this kind of construct.

Answer (score 0):

Use the splice method to remove the item from the array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

**Add items to the array:**
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.splice(2,0,"Lemon","Kiwi");

**The result of fruits will be:**
Banana,Orange,Lemon,Kiwi,Apple,Mango

**At position 2, remove 2 items:**
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

fruits.splice(2,2);

**The result of fruits will be:**
Banana,Orange